# Is there any way to get the route scope from a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a polymorphic controller in rails, and my question is, is there any way for me to get the scope of the requester. for example, the rout is `/users/1/messages`, the request goes to the `MessagesController`, in that controller, is there any way to get the `users` portion of the route? or in this case it could also be `admin` or something else.

I cant just set up an if statement structure, because in this case, `POST '/users/1/messages' is a message going to a user, perhaps from an admin.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the string 'users'? If so, you could look at parsing `request.url`

Comment: Hmm... I'm not terribly opposed to doing that, I was hoping to do something a little less hack-ish, but that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you should have put a type field (e.g. `messagable_type`), a message instance has the corresponding class (e.g. `User`) and the id field (e.g. `messagable_id`) will have the point to the id of the user. so you can ask a message instance:

```
 message.messagable
 => user
```

it will return the user instance.

If you have a url such as: `/users/1/messages` and you want use this:

```
def load_messagable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
  @messagable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end
```

This is the solution given by Ryan Bates in this episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154

Comment: Interesting, I like that, and on the next version of my site I will definitely use that to dry up controllers.